# 4 objects with own textures into 1?

Tags: texturing, uv, objects, baking

I have 4 objects, each has it's own texture. However they share same UV, so it means even though they all use own 1024x1024 textures, they all fit into one 1024x1024 texture.

How can I create 1 single texture that would contain all those textures?

I tried texture baking, but then one part just becomes very bright-white, and there appears to be some overlapping places because after ambient occlusion each part has extensive things.

I had better success with manually merging textures into one in GIMP. I need to redo it from start but somehow make it so ambient occlusion wouldn't make such wide things on texture edges?

Comment: I duplicate the objects and join them into a combined object that I use for baking. I'd love to know a more organised way.

Comment: Well I changed margin to one px so now all details have one px outline. Then I manually edit texture for each part, after what I place that part to main texture.